# Codename Combobox: Is it advisable using in codename one applications?

Tags: combobox, codenameone

Is it not advisable to use combobox in codename one apps for ios devices?

Comment: First, questions should be specific issues in a coding space.  If you are having a specific issue, you should edit your question and be very clear on your issue and give examples.  A good stackoverflow question may take you ~1 hour to write depending on your question.

Comment: Oh my apologies! I should do better next time. After all, this is my first question in stackoverflow but that should not be an excuse. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Combo boxes aren't used in iOS native applications. You can use it but it will look alien to iOS users who only run into combo boxes in web apps and not in native apps.

Use lists, pickers etc. instead.

Comment: Hello Shai, aside from it would look alien to iOS users will combobox create others cons like performance perhaps? Also, I did set .setActAsSpinnerDialog to true thinking it might help with the looks.. Thanks!

Comment: The act as spinner isn't something we support anymore. It won't have performance overhead but it is a complex widget with many culprits

Comment: I guess i'll have to use something else other than combobox then. Thank you!